# How to play sound once in loop in LWJGL/Slick2D

Tags: java, loops, audio, lwjgl, slick2d

I want to play once a sound effect when someone place mouse inside button in MainMenu. Problem is here - MainMenu is in loop, so my sound repeat all the time. How to play sound just once when someone place mouse inside button?

Button:

```
if(mouse is in position X = <0,100> and Y = <0,100>){
    drawButton( X = 0, Y = 0, X2 = 100, Y2 = 100);
}
```

Button is in loop:

```
while( we are in MainMenu state )
{
    if(mouse is in position X = <0,100> and Y = <0,100>){
        drawButton( X = 0, Y = 0, X2 = 100, Y2 = 100);
    }
}
```

Sound:

```
Music Sound_1 = new Music("res/Sound/Sound_1.wav");
```

Play sound:

```
Sound_1.play(1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Code:

```
while( we are in MainMenu state )
{
    if(mouse is in position X = <0,100> and Y = <0,100>){
        Sound_1.play(1.0f, 1.0f); <- IT MUST PLAY JUST ONCE WHENEVER MOUSE IS IN BUTTON
        drawButton( X = 0, Y = 0, X2 = 100, Y2 = 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the sound is already playing, by calling (using your example sound variable Sound_1):

```
if(mouse is in position) {
    if(!sound_1.playing()) {
        sound_1.play(1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    drawButton(x,y,x2,y2);
}
```

With the .playing() method that Sound/Music objects have in slick, it will return a boolean true if the sound is currently playing, and false if it is not. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried do this, but thinking is still here - it is in loop, so if mouse is on button, it just check if sound_1 isn't playing all the time, sound_1 is 1 second sound, so sound repeat all the time, because after 1 second, sound isn't playing so that "if(!sound_1.playing)" - is repeated.

Comment: Well you will probably need a global boolean value in that case, saying that if the mouse is hovering over a button, turn it to true and don't play the sound if that value is true, and then as an else statement, just set that boolean variable to false because it's not hovering on a button

Answer (score 0):

Before calling your loop, add a Boolean that tracks if the game should play the sound:

```
boolean playSound = false;
```

Then, when you call your loop, do this:

```
    loop() {
        playSound = true;

        if (/**Mouse is on the button*/) {playSound = true;}
        else {playSound = false}

        //If playSound is true, then play the sound
        if (playSound) {sound.play(1.0f, 1.0f);}
        else 
            return;
     }
```

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a boolean that determines whether we have already played the sound.

```
boolean soundHasPlayed = false;
while( we are in MainMenu state )
{
    if(mouse is in position X = <0,100> and Y = <0,100>){
        if (!soundHasPlayed) // only do this if we haven't played the sound yet
        {
            Sound_1.play(1.0f, 1.0f);
            drawButton( X = 0, Y = 0, X2 = 100, Y2 = 100);
            soundHasPlayed = true; // don't play it again until we leave the button
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // We left the button, so we can play it again if we ever enter the button again.  
        // (Omit this if you really only want it to play once, ever, even if they mouse over the button again.)
        soundHasPlayed = false;
    }
}
```